# Calculated field with images and multi-value column

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, calculated-column

Say I have this list that looks like this:

```
  Title            Link
  -----            -----
  Cat              /animals/cats.aspx
  Dog              /animals/dogs.aspx
  Duck             /animals/ducks.aspx
```

I then get a requirement to be able to add resources to each item, and display an image if it does.
The list would then look something like:

```
  Title            Link                 Resources                          HasResources
  -----            -----                ---------                          ------------  
  Cat              /animals/cats.aspx   Reference guide.pdf; Kittens.ppt   [icon.png here]
  Dog              /animals/dogs.aspx   Dog video 1.flv                    [icon.png here]
  Duck             /animals/ducks.aspx
```

Is this even possible? How do I go about doing this?
Or if this isn't, what would be a good approach to this?
I've thought about a multi-value fill-in Choice column for `Resources` and a Calculated field for `HasResources`, but I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the 'Resources' to be clickable, or do you just want to show that there are resources attached to that item?

To get the 'HasResources' column to work the way you want, I would actually display this list as a Data View Web Part, and use conditional formatting to display an image depending on the 'Resources' data.

You wouldn't need to create the 'HasResources' column in the list at all, you would just add an additional column to the DVWP template, and put the image in the cell. Then you would apply conditional formatting to the image to hide it if the 'Resources' field is blank.

Comment: Preferably the resources would be in a `<a href="link">Title</a>` format. This would is a great idea, however, I want to make a change to the list data itself and not just on the view.